# Variable batch size in tensorflow and CNN

Tags: tensorflow

I want to feed in a 1-D CNN a sequence of fixed length and want it to make a prediction (regression), but I want to have a variable batch size during training. The tutorials are not really helpful.

In my input layer I have something like this:

```
input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, sequence_length], name="input")
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1], name="y")
```

so I assume the `None` dimension, can be the a variable batch size of any number, so the current `input` dimension is `batch_size * sequence_length` and I am supposed to feed the network a 2d np array with dimensions `any * sequence_length`

`tf.nn.conv1d` expects 3-D, since my input is a single channel that is 1 np array of `sequence_length` observations the input I will need to feed to the cnn should be `1*batch_size * sequence_length`, if I had on the other hand 2 different sequences that I combine to predict a single value in the end it would have been `2*batch_size * sequence_length` and I would also need to concatenate the 2 different channels. So in my case I need

```
input = tf.expand_dims(input, -1)
```

and then the filter also follow the same:

```
filter_size = 5
channel_size = 1
num_filters = 10
filter_shape = [filter_size, channel_size, num_filters]
filters = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(filter_shape, stddev=0.1), name="filters")
tf.nn.conv1d(value=input, filters=filters, stride=1)
```

After that I add a FC layer, but the network isn't able to learn anything, even the a basic function such as sin(x), does the code above look correct?

Also how can I do a maxpooling?